# mToast.cancel() is not working

Tags: java, android

I made a method to make sure my toast messages will be displayed immediately, without having to wait the previous toast to dissapear. The method :

```
public void myToaster(String message){
     if(mToast!=null){
         mToast.cancel();
     }
     mToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I'm using Android Studio with API23.

Comment: And where are you setting `mToast` ? It obviosuly always null so cancel is never called

Comment: I set it globally without any value since I'm using it for multiple methods. Then I call it repeatedly throughout the whole activity.

Toast mToast; //set globally

<inside onCreate, and btnCancel.setOnClickListener>
myToaster("Texts");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mToast` is never `assigned`/`reassigned` . This

```
mToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

should be

```
mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
mToast.show();
```

`Toast.cancel` doesn't remove the current Toast immediately. The fade out animation takes place nevertheless

Comment: `public void myToaster(String message) {
     if (mToast != null) { 
        mToast.cancel(); 
    } 
    mToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG); mToast.show(); 
}`

 Thanks. This worked exactly as I want to now